# Typescript object same structure but different types, how to union?

Tags: typescript, object, union

```
  export interface TEST {
   action: 'action1' | 'action2' | 'action3',
   params: User | BadUser
  }

  interface User {
   name: string | null,
   date: string | null,
   ...
  }

  interface BadUser {
   badName: string | null,
   badDate: string | null,
   ...
  }
```

How to acces someUser.params.name or someBadUser.params.badName correctly ?

Comment: User-defined type guards using [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to check if a field is present on the `params`:

```js
function something(thing: TEST) {
    if ("name" in thing.params) {
        return thing.params.date;
    } else {
        return thing.params.badDate;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=16&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgFQFEBlfOAbwCg4a4cYEIkAuOAcnsaQEY24AfdpyYAmPoI7YGTAMxsA3NVphMUTAFsAzqwCqmtALgAhTABM9aRQF9KlZKgw48FqBSU0kG4K00woyAHNDJABXABswxVo4U0xUHz9A4PDIyhs7FDQsXGMzFzdogCMzADkvBP8kIMFQiKjaYtMAETjvOF9K6rha1PT0EKQpLnaIdWAYAAtAgApJwNYiUgBKAtoEdDhpgCJPMa3EJDg5qoA6FTUtFapo6KhxkKhD44Cz1Q1NE9jUeporOGAwvpVjc4HcYA8nlNTud3idGi1vu44DYrEA)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "accessing the property correctly" so I'll assume two possible cases

1. You want to make sure `params` is of type `User` so you can access `params.name` or vice versa
   Create a `type guard` method to check which interface matches the object

```js
const isUser = (obj: User | BadUser): obj is User => 'name' in obj;
const isBadUser = (obj: User | BadUser): obj is BadUser => 'badDate' in obj;

if (isUser(someUser.params))
    someUser.params   // <- User
else someUser.params  // <- BadUser
```

You can find more about [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) in the typescript handbook.

2. You want the intellisense to add both definitions to the object so all four properties are accepted
   In this case, you need to change from an `Union` to an `Intersection`

```js
export interface TEST {
   action: 'action1' | 'action2' | 'action3',
   params: User & BadUser
}
```

In this way, it will be necessary to attend to both types at the same time.

You can find more about [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) in the old typescript handbook.

I hope one of these solves your question.

Answer (score -1):

```
let test: TEST = {};

return test.params.name ?? test.params.badName;    
or
return test.params.date ?? test.params.badDate;
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.